# Missing CSS and images after URL rewrite

Tags: css, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

There are a lot of info about this here at Stackoverflow, but nothing seems to work for me! I have rewritten some URL in the .htaccess file and it's working, but then I discovered that the CSS and images was lost. And I read and read about how to change path from relative to absolute, but I'm not shore this helps or perhaps I'm doing this the wrong way!?

.htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^bilder-byggnader-kopenhamn$ /?p=byggnader [L]
RewriteRule ^bilder$ /?p=byggnader [L]
RewriteRule ^byggnad/(.+)$ /?p=byggnad&id=$1 [L]
```

It's only the third row in the .htaccess file that cause this problem. First and second row don't affect the CSS and images.

From the beginning my CSS file was just like this `styelsheet.css` since it's located in the root. I then changed it to `http://127.0.0.1/stylesheet.css`, but it still doesn't work. I haven't yet done this with the images, but I guess I should be the same there like `http://127.0.0.1/images/image.jpg`.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider adding:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

so rewrite rule won't work for existing files and directories (for example for images and stylesheets)

Comment: So if you remove 3rd line you will see in your page css and images properly and when you add it you don't?

Comment: When I used your code in my site, nothing happened, all my images and CSS are displayed correctly. Have you added the code I published in the answer before the line that causes problem? If it doesn't help in this place unfortunately I don't know what's wrong

Comment: No, it's still the same problem! :(

Answer (score 0):

First modify your rules like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^bilder-byggnader-kopenhamn$ /?p=byggnader [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^bilder$ /?p=byggnader [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^byggnad/(.+)$ /?p=byggnad&id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Then make sure to use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.